# Problem with correlation matrix for large table in R

Tags: r, plot, correlation

I have a data table like below.

```
data table1:

Cty  LR1998  LR1999....LR2018  SM1998  SM1999 ..... SM2018
1    0.1     2.5 ....  5.2     14.52   58.62  ..... 69.2  
7    0       50.2 ...  10.6    25.5    80.2   ..... 80.5 
.
.
```

I need to find the correlation (pearson) for each "Cty" for the time period from 1998 to 2018 using the LR and SM variables for this time period.

I would also like to create a nice correlation plot as well.

Can somebody guide me how to perform this using R? I know how to use "cor"function but do not know how to use that for a large data table.

```
Example Output:

Cty  Cor   p-value
1    0.16  0.125
7    0.32  <0.05
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it correct that you want the correlation between Cty's? i.e. the correlation between the rows?

Comment: I want the correlation for each row between LR and SM variables from 1998 to 2018. I guess I want correlation for each Cty.

Comment: That output makes no sense. The first row is country 1's correlation *with whom*?

Comment: Output is an example but values are not correct. Output table Cty 1 correlation should be with data in the first row of data table1 from LR1998 to LR2018 and with SM1998 to SM 2018.

Comment: I understand that the values themselves are place-holders. My point is that you cannot have correlation with just one group. It would need to include perhaps `Cty1` and `Cty2`, as in my answer below. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the correlation plot, you can try this: Transpose the data frame and use the 'pairs' function

pairs(t(table1[-1]))

Comment: Did you actually try to transpose a `data.frame` with one `character` column and the rest `numeric`? The tranposition works, but there is nothing numeric. I suggest instead `t(table1[-1])` to remove the first (char) column assuming all others are numeric, or `t(table1[c(...)])` where `...` is a vector of column numbers or names to keep.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assume it is just an identifier and does not need to be included in the correlation computation. I will edit the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get correlation between countries, it might help to reshape the data. Though there's a base `reshape` function, I've always found it confusing, so I often use `tidyr` (or `data.table`) for reshaping operations.

First, some data:

```
set.seed(2)
n <- 6
x <- cbind.data.frame(
  CTY = LETTERS[seq_len(n)],
  sapply(paste0("LR", 2000:2006), function(ign) runif(n)),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

Reshaping, so that each country is unique vertically (removing my unnecessarily-complicated `tidyr` method with the should-have-been-obvious `t`, thanks pooja p):

```
y <- `colnames<-`(t(x[-1]), x[[1]])
cor(y)
```

(The biggest difference between my now-removed `gather`/`spread` approach is that this is still a `matrix`, trivially converted with `as.data.frame` if needed. It should not be necessary here.)

Now the correlation is rather straight-forward.

```
cor(y)
#        A      B       C       D      E      F
# A  1.000 -0.435 -0.1443 -0.2010  0.736 -0.471
# B -0.435  1.000 -0.3825 -0.3493 -0.145  0.279
# C -0.144 -0.382  1.0000  0.0885 -0.426  0.447
# D -0.201 -0.349  0.0885  1.0000 -0.523 -0.128
# E  0.736 -0.145 -0.4261 -0.5232  1.000 -0.121
# F -0.471  0.279  0.4467 -0.1279 -0.121  1.000
```

With the data in this format, adapting to the use of `cor.test` is a little more work. I'll lean on more of the `tidyverse` for this:

```
# library(purrr)
crossing(a=x$CTY, b=x$CTY) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(bind_cols(.,
               purrr::map2_dfc(.$a, .$b,
                               ~ as.data.frame(cor.test(y[,.x], y[,.y])[c("estimate", "p.value")]))
               )) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 36 x 4
#    a     b     estimate p.value
#  * <chr> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 A     A        1      0     
#  2 A     B       -0.435  0.329 
#  3 A     C       -0.144  0.757 
#  4 A     D       -0.201  0.666 
#  5 A     E        0.736  0.0591
#  6 A     F       -0.471  0.286 
#  7 B     A       -0.435  0.329 
#  8 B     B        1      0     
#  9 B     C       -0.382  0.397 
# 10 B     D       -0.349  0.443 
# # ... with 26 more rows
```

Since your correlation tests are associative (the same as `a,b` and `b,a`), then we can remove the duplicates and run tests with:

```
crossing(a=x$CTY, b=x$CTY) %>%
  transmute(a1 = pmin(a,b), b1 = pmax(a,b)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(bind_cols(.,
               purrr::map2_dfc(.$a1, .$b1,
                               ~ as.data.frame(cor.test(y[,.x], y[,.y])[c("estimate", "p.value")]))
               )) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 21 x 4 ...
```